# How to connect the dll files in the process of code execution in C++?

Tags: c++, qt5

There is a compiled program written in QT (C++). In the program folder is added dll file all the names of Lib1.dll, Lib2.dll, etc. How can I get these libraries in the process of implementation of the program ? I.e. initially the program is compiled without them

For example:

```
int n = 10;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
       include("lib"+i+".dll");
}
```

Comment: There are many [DLL-related functions in the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Check them out.

Comment: And what does this question has to do with Qt4 and the Brainfuck language? Please edit your question to include only relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was solved by using QLibrary

```
 for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {            
       QString* pLoadLib =&sDrivers[i]; //запоминаем адрес переменной
       std::cout<<sDrivers[i].toUtf8().constData()<<"\n";//выводим в консоль
       QLibrary lib(*pLoadLib); //Разименование адреса - текст пути к ДЛЛ
       if (!lib.load())
          {
             std::cout<<"driver not loaded\n";//error
          }
       else
          {   typedef QString (*FuncType) (const QString&);
                    FuncType func = (FuncType)(lib.resolve("FuncName")); //Определяем функцию func как функция OddUpper из dll
                    if (func)
                    {
                       QString test = func("working");
                       qDebug()<<test;
                    }
                    if (!func)
                    {
                        std::cout<<"func not loaded";
                    }
                    lib.unload();
                }
    }
```